# search form that redirects to search results page, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

Hi how can I edit this code so when I click on search, I am redirected to specifed page not stay on the same?

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get',:id => "products_search" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>  
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> </li>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= form_tag "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions", :method => 'get',:id => "products_search" do %>
```

Put whatever you need in place of that URL.
for more info please look at the form_tag helper documentation

But if you need actually to be trough that path you were using, you have to use a redirect or a forwarding.
For using a forwarding just call the name of the next action near the end of that action yuo are calling.
Something like:

```
def another_action
...
end

def product
...
  another_action
end
```

For using a redirect just do it like:

```
def products
 redirect_to another_action 
end
```